# Find joint pdf of uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have three random variables where $ a $ and $b$ are uniformly distributed between $[-1/2, 1/2]$ and $c = a + b$. Also, $b$ is independent of $a$. How can I find the joint pdf of $a$ and $c$?

So far I've been looking at this formula:

[Formula for calculating joint pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45aoB.png)

And I know that $f_a = r_1(x)$, the rectangular function with width 1. How can I calculate $f_{c|a}$?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220201/sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables) This is a similar question with an answer.

Comment: @callculus Here the user is asking for the joint, so perhaps [this one instead](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195947)? Note that this question "intended" to ask for the marginal, while both answers there contain the joint.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Sure. But if I´m right the link I´ve posted the marginal is $f_X(z-y)=f_{X|Z}(z-y)$. Maybe I´m wrong.